# Children's book - front cover displays blonde child playing flute in a field

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

The book is about a part-magical child who was born again into a human family. He has only one line on his palm, unlike other humans and doesn't know who is magical mother was. I believe it's a middle-grade chapter book.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: If you remember anything else or have something to add you can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 17):

I found the answer!!! It's *[The Moorchild](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/309480.The_Moorchild) (1998)* by Eloise McGraw

[image]

Synopsis from Goodreads:

> Half moorfolk and half human, and unable to shape-shift or disappear at will, Moql threatens the safety of the Band. So the Folk banish her and send her to live among humans as a changeling. Named Saaski by the couple for whose real baby she was swapped, she grows up taunted and feared by the villagers for being different, and is comfortable only on the moor, playing strange music on her bagpipes.
>
> As Saaski grows up, memories from her forgotten past with the Folks slowly emerge. But so do emotions from her human side, and she begins to realize the terrible wrong the Folk have done to the humans she calls Da and Mumma. She is determined to restore their child to them, even if it means a dangerous return to the world that has already rejected her once.

Comment: It'll be a day or so before you can do so, but don't forget to accept your own answer -- the check box on the left, under the score.